# Bitcoin transaction not confirmed since 3 days ago

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, unconfirmed-transactions, transaction-id

Hello I might sound stupid but it’s been three days since I issued bitcoin transactions, all unconfirmed so far. I use Blockchain.com to manage my wallet and have done everything normally (I think, as I usually do).
How long does it take for the blockchain to cancel unconfirmed transactions?
I am discredited in the face of my buyer and this situation may create problems for me in the days to come, I will leave the TXs of the transactions if u good will could help me that would make me very happy.
Here are the TXs:
e122bccd8ccbfe19f0263afb33b5458fa951d4c6ea71743e1bad9baabdbf3904
b51723ef74039503d966f2c90b05cf71774bbc12968ef60276996141ef561293

Answer (score 2):

You set the fee rate to 6 sat/vbyte. That's very low, median fee in recent blocks has been 30-70 sat/vbyte. See [mempool.space](https://www.mempool.space).

You could wait until the weekend when the [mining difficulty is expected to drop by more than 25%](https://www.coinwarz.com/mining/bitcoin/difficulty-chart). This will decrease fees as more blocks can be mined per hour. The difficulty drop happens around 1AM UTC on Saturday.

Alternatively, you could bump the fees. You have RBF disabled, but you could do CPFP (child-pays-for-parent). How you do this depends on your wallet. But it would basically spend the UTXO from your second TX (b5172...) again, but this time with a much higher sat/vbyte. Miners could then decide to include your 3 transactions in their blocks.

Given that you already created a descendant transaction, your new fee has to pay for a total of 3 transactions. So I would set it higher than the median fee rate from mempool.space.